# How to give a variable the value "empty sequence"?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I would like to have a variable with the empty sequence as value.
(For what it might be worth, it is mostly for debugging purposes, e.g. passing it as a parameter to my functions)

For the time being I am using something along the lines of

> <xsl:variable name="empty_sequence" select="a_node_name_that_does_not_exist"/>

but it feels hackish and I would prefer something more readable anyway. What other options are there?

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#variable-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `()` to denote an empty sequence e.g. `<xsl:variable name="empty-seq" select="()"/>`.